# How to pass a python list to C function (dll) using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, dll

**Background**

I have some analysis software in Python I must pass a list of 4096 bytes (*which looks like this* `[80, 56, 49, 50, 229, 55, 55, 0, 77, ......]`) to a dll, so that the dll writes it to a device.

1. The bytes to be written are stored in variable name data
2. The c function (in dll) which has to be called from python is

   `int _DLL_BUILD_ IO_DataWrite(HANDLE hDevice, unsigned char* p_pBuff, unsigned char p_nByteCntInBuff);`
3. I have no access to the dll code

**Method tried**

I tried to declare a data type

```
data_tx = (ctypes.c_uint8 * len(data))(*data)
```

and called the function

```
ret = self.sisdll.IO_DataWrite(self.handle, ctypes.byref(data_tx), ctypes.c_uint8(pending_bytes))
```

**Problem**

There seems to be no error but its not working. The API call works with C and C++.

Am I doing this correct. Could anyone please kindly point the mistake for me?

Comment: Have you tried defining the argument types: `IO_DataWrite.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_uint8), c_uint8]`?

Comment: Usually, I do `data_tx = (ctypes.c_uint8 * len(data))()` and afterwards copy the data into the array and call the library using  `ctypes.byref`. Could you try this instead of constructing your array from data

Comment: @JensMunk Turn that into an answer, it's the right answer

Comment: @zwol I do that later today. Have been away for a while

Comment: @JensMunk please turn it into an answer. Its correct !!!!!

Comment: I do that when I get of work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you try to achieve can be done like this.

Interface header, say functions.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "functions_export.h" // Defining FUNCTIONS_API
FUNCTIONS_API int GetSomeData(uint32_t output[32]);
```

C source, functions.c

```
#include "functions.h"
int GetSomeData(uint32_t output[32]) {
  output[0] = 37;
}
```

In python, you simply write

```
import ctypes
hDLL = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("functions.dll")
output = (ctypes.c_uint32 * 32)()
hDLL.GetSomeData(ctypes.byref(output))
print(output[0])
```

You should see the number 37 printed on the screen.